# Can you help identify this classy, German-built city bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I rode this bike in Germany in the summer and it was great.

I'd like to buy it but I didn't write down the brand, model, or anything.

I just remember that it said on the frame, quite proudly, that it was made in Germany.

It had a 3-gear hub and built-in dynamo lights.

[image: Unknown classy, old-fasihoned style bike]

[image: Cannot read the brand name of this bike]

Comment: Is this the only picture? The brand and model are on the down tube and seat tube.

Comment: @jqning, I found another photo where it's a bit more visible, but I still can't make it out/recognize it.

Comment: One possibility is a [Kalkhoff](http://www.kalkhoff-bikes.com/en/bikes/my-bike/allround/jubilee-8r-8-g.html), but the fenders don't quite match and the headlight seems a hair different.

Comment: I also see some [Stevens](http://www.stevensbikes.de/2012/index.php?bik_id=96&cou=CA&lang=en_US) bikes that look close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the 2015 version of the [Winora Aruba](https://www.winora.com/at/en/bikes/city/lifestyle/aruba-atbik77476?id=4055008846), 8-speed bike.

Solid build, but sadly, it's a bit too expensive for my needs as a city bike: costs around €700 new.